# How can I convert a HTML Page to PDF using Django

Tags: python, django, pdf

I have a web app in Django. It's a plataform to store bills and invoices. Now i'm trying to export those bills un PDF.

I'm using xhtml2pdf but it's not working.

I'm using this code for testing:
http://obroll.com/generate-pdf-with-xhtml2pdf-pisa-in-django-examples/

It doesnt give any errors but doesnt generate the PDF documentos.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try using this code. It works for me.
Change "template_testing.html" for your template and add your data to render on "data = {}"

views.py:

```
import os
from django.conf import settings
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import Context
from django.template.loader import get_template
import datetime
from xhtml2pdf import pisa 


def generate_PDF(request):
    data = {}

    template = get_template('template_testing.html')
    html  = template.render(Context(data))

    file = open('test.pdf', "w+b")
    pisaStatus = pisa.CreatePDF(html.encode('utf-8'), dest=file,
            encoding='utf-8')

    file.seek(0)
    pdf = file.read()
    file.close()            
    return HttpResponse(pdf, 'application/pdf')
```

Comment: Thanks for the solutions, concise and functional. It works for me when css code and html are inside the same code. However, css are all dropped if css code are stored in a different folder. Do you have any suggestion on that?

Comment: Worth noting that this is only supported by Python 2.x at the moment. Python 3 will throw errors if importing xhtml2pdf