# Get PDF from HTML page with xhtml2pdf Django

Tags: python, html, django, pdf

I get a little problem with my function letting to get a `PDF file` from my `HTML view`.

My script comes from : [Convert a HTML page to PDF using Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23767073/how-can-i-convert-a-html-page-to-pdf-using-django)

From a form, I generate a resume which could be exportable to PDF file.

**My function looks like :**

```
def BirthCertificate_PDF(request, id) :

    birthcertificate = get_object_or_404(BirthCertificate, pk=id)

    data = {}

    template = get_template('BC_raw.html')
    html  = template.render(Context(data))

    file = open('test.pdf', "w+b")
    pisaStatus = pisa.CreatePDF(html.encode('utf-8'), dest=file,
            encoding='utf-8')

    file.seek(0)
    pdf = file.read()
    file.close()

    return HttpResponse(pdf, 'application/pdf')
```

**And my template looks like :**

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<h2 align="center"> ACTE DE NAISSANCE </align> </h2>

{% block content %} 

<h3 align = "right"> Acte de Naissance n° {{birthcertificate.id}} </align> </h3>

<h3> Informations concernant l'enfant : </h3>
<li> Nom de l'enfant : {{birthcertificate.lastname}}</li>
<li>Prénom(s) de l'enfant : {{birthcertificate.firstname}}</li>
<li>Est né(e) à : {{birthcertificate.birthcity}}</li>
<li>Le : {{birthcertificate.birthday}} à {{birthcertificate.birthhour}}</li>
<li>De sexe : {{birthcertificate.sex}}</li>

<hr width = "50%"></hr>

<h3> Informations concernant le père : </h3>
<li>Fils ou fille du nommé : {{birthcertificate.fk_parent1.lastname}} {{birthcertificate.fk_parent1.firstname}}</li> <!-- Get only firstname and lastname element -->
<li>Né le : {{birthcertificate.fk_parent1.birthday}}</li> <!-- Get only birthday element -->
<li>A : {{birthcertificate.fk_parent1.birthcity}}</li> <!-- Get only birthcity element -->
<li>De nationalité : {{birthcertificate.fk_parent1.nationality}}</li> <!-- Get only nationality element -->
<li>Domicilié au : {{birthcertificate.fk_parent1.adress}}</li> 
<li>A : {{birthcertificate.fk_parent1.city}} ({{birthcertificate.fk_parent1.zip}}) - {{birthcertificate.fk_parent1.country}}</li> <!-- Get only adress, zip, city, country element -->
<li>Exerçant la profession de : {{birthcertificate.fk_parent1.job}}</li> <!-- Get only job element -->

<hr width = "50%"></hr>

<h3> Informations concernant la mère : </h3>
<li>Fils ou fille de la nommée : {{birthcertificate.fk_parent2.lastname}} {{birthcertificate.fk_parent2.firstname}}</li> <!-- Get only firstname and lastname element -->
<li>Née le : {{birthcertificate.fk_parent2.birthday}}</li> <!-- Get only birthday element -->
<li>A : {{birthcertificate.fk_parent2.birthcity}}</li> <!-- Get only birthcity element -->
<li>De nationalité : {{birthcertificate.fk_parent2.nationality}}</li> <!-- Get only nationality element -->
<li>Domiciliée au : {{birthcertificate.fk_parent2.adress}}</li> 
<li>A : {{birthcertificate.fk_parent2.city}} ({{birthcertificate.fk_parent2.zip}}) - {{birthcertificate.fk_parent2.country}}</li> 
<li>Exerçant la profession de : {{birthcertificate.fk_parent2.job}}</li> <!-- Get only job element -->

<br></br>

<h3> Par la présente, l'Officier d'Etat Civil certifie la sincérité de la présente déclaration </h3>

<h3 align = "right"> L'Officier d'Etat Civil </align> </h3>
<h3 align = "right"> Signature et tampon </align> </h3>

{% endblock %}
```

But, even if I get a good PDF file, all Python variables missed from this file.

**So my question is :** How I can display my HTML background and variables on my PDF ?

My PDF looks like :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the birthcertificate object in the data dictionary. It is empty the way you are sending it now.

Change the line:

```
data = {}
```

to

```
data = {'birthcertificate': birthcertificate, }
```

Comment: I didn't know because I'm really stuck with Django ! Now, I have learned something so Thank you !

Comment: no problem. the data is passed with your `html  = template.render(Context(data))` command. As it was, the context was getting an empty dictionary (data).